# Is complement of LL(k) grammar context free?

Tags: formal-languages

Is complement of [LL(k) grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) context free?

Comment: What is LL(k)??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Answer (score 4):

In general, the complement of a context-free language is not context-free.  However, [LL(k) languages are a strict subset of the deterministic CFLs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31733/can-i-have-an-ll-grammar-for-every-deterministic-context-free-language).

The complement of a DCFL is also a DCFL, because it can be recognized by the same deterministic push-down automaton, just with the "accept" and "reject" states swapped.

So the answer to your question appears to be "yes, in fact it is deterministic context-free."